# How to return from a top level function while inside an inner function in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, return

There are two functions, say `func1` and `func2`. `func2` is an inner function of `func1` and based on a condition I wish to return from func1, meaning end execution of func1. How do I do that in kotlin?

```
fun func1(){
    fun func2(){
        if(someCondition){
            ...

            return@func1 //How do I do this? since it says return not allowed here
        }
    }

    ...

    func2()
}
```

Comment: Inner function can return a Boolean. Outer function checks result to determine whether it should return immediately or continue.

Comment: Thanks. That actually solves my problem. I cant believe I couldn't think of this solution and feel a little stupid for asking the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't make sense in all cases, as a nested function might outlive the scope of the containing function in some cases. Here's an example of that:

```kotlin
var x: () -> Unit = {}

fun func1() {
    fun func2() {}

    x = ::func2
}
```

Here, it would not make sense to allow returns for `func1` from `func2`. By the time `x` is called, there might not even be an active call to `func1`. This is basically the topic of non-local returns, which you need inline functions for (see [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns)). Those, unfortunately, are not available as local functions (at least not yet).

For your specific case, you're probably stuck with signaling that you want a return from `func1` by using the return value of `func2` and checking for it in `func1`. (Or an exception, which wouldn't be nice to use for control flow like this.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had not considered that func2 could live beyond the scope of func1. Good point. I had tried inlining func2, but ran into limitations as locally its not possible yet as you mentioned. I however was able to solve with a very simple solution as proposed by @Tenfour04.

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion too, that's what I meant by the last paragraph (though perhaps it wasn't that clear).

Comment: I did read that too and the reiteration of the same point made by Tenfour confirmed what I needed to do. Thanks again!